# Refactoring pseudo-enum models to enums

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model named `article_status`, which does nothing more than providing statuses to the articles. I want to drop this `article_status` table and use `enum` within the `article` model directly.

So, I've created a new migration but my problem is how to write SQL to update the columns.

```rb
class AddStatusToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :articles, :status, :integer
    add_index :articles, :status

    execute <<~SQL
      # Write SQL here
    SQL

    change_column :articles, :status, :integer, null: false
  end
end
```

For the SQL part, I want the equivalent of:

```rb
Article.all.each do |article|
  article.update_columns(status: article.article_status.name.parameterize.underscore)
end
```

In my `article` model:

```rb
enum status: { draft: 0, in_review: 1, reviewed: 2, published: 3, deleted: 4 }, _default: :draft
```

I added the `enum` like this.

**PS**: I'm using Postgres as my database.

Comment: How many records are there in the table? Is it really worth it to convert the logic into pure SQL? Are there only five different values in the old table or does the SQL need to be able to handle other values too?

Comment: @spickermann I have the `belongs_to` association and some validations which I want to remove too. If I remove it and write ruby-specific code like above, it raises an error saying, undefined method `article_status_id`. It has very few records, but because of this error, I'm opting for SQL. It only has five different values.

Comment: If you already removed the `article_status_id` how do you know what status belongs to what article? How can that be worked out in SQL then?

Comment: I haven't removed the column `article_status_id`, nor have I dropped the `article_status` table. I just removed the rails specific code. `belongs_to :article_status`. By doing so and writing rails logic instead of SQL, I get the error mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
statuses = ArticleStatus
  .pluck(:id, :name)
  .map { |(id, name)| [id, name..parameterize.underscore] }
  .to_h

Article.find_each do |article|
  article.update_columns(status: statuses[article. article_status_id])
end
```